# What is the meaning of the "on and off"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In film called *The Basketball Diaries (1995)*, Jim narrate this lines while having drugss and drinks with his friends:

> Headquarters home **on and off** to every down-and-out junkie and wino
>   from 14th Street to the Bowery. It's like a f*cking all-star team.

Comment: Most of us reading this question will have no idea who "Jim" is. Assuming this is from a book or a movie, please, tell us where you found it. (Please do this for your future questions as well; [here is a detailed meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) explaining why.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is most likely to imply that it is *not always* the headquarters home for these people.

The term "on and off" suggests that it is used as the headquarters intermittently; sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't:

> **on and off**
>
> 1. intermittently.
>
>    "it rained on and off most of the afternoon"